# Issues with using negative numbers in a prompt box

Tags: javascript, html, css, multidimensional-array

Very new to JavaScript, the first programming language I learned was Java. I am trying to make a simple website that displays the shortest distance between an infinite number of points using prompt boxes and a 2D array.

This code works as expected, however when one of the points has a negative number in it, nothing ever displays for an answer, throwing the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at run (index.html:54)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:63)
```

Google Chrome highlights the error at this line:

```
toRun = "Shortest distance is " + min + " with these points: (" + finalPoints[0][0] + ", " + finalPoints[1][0] + ") and (" + finalPoints[0][1] + ", " + finalPoints[1][1] + ").";
```

How can I get this program to work with negative numbers as well?

```js
function run() {
  var x, y;
  var finalPoints = [];
  var min = 0;
  var toRun;
  var temp;
  var list = []; //using 2d array to store points
  while (true) {
    x = prompt("Enter an X-Value: ");
    if (x == null || x == "") {
      break;
    }
    y = prompt("Enter a Y-Value: ");
    if (y == null || y == "") {
      break;
    }
    list.push([x, y]);
  }
  if (list.length < 2) {
    toRun = "Sorry, you didn't enter enough points for this program to run correctly. Please try again.";
  } else if (list.length == 2) {
    toRun = "Distance between points (" + list[0][0] + ", " + list[0][1] + ") and (" + list[1][0] + ", " + list[1][1] + ") is " + Math.sqrt(Math.pow((list[0][0] - list[1][0]), 2) + Math.pow((list[0][1] - list[1][1]), 2));
  } else {
    min = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((list[0][0] - list[1][0]), 2) + Math.pow((list[0][1] - list[1][1]), 2));
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        temp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((list[i][0] - list[j][0]), 2) + Math.pow((list[i][1] - list[j][1]), 2));
        if (temp < min && temp != 0) {
          min = temp;
          finalPoints.push([list[i][0], list[j][0]]);
          finalPoints.push([list[i][1], list[j][1]]);
        }
      }
    }
    toRun = "Shortest distance is " + min + " with these points: (" + finalPoints[0][0] + ", " + finalPoints[1][0] + ") and (" + finalPoints[0][1] + ", " + finalPoints[1][1] + ").";
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = toRun;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
}

p,
button,
h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<h3>Continue entering points. When done, click cancel or don't enter anything.</h3>
<br>
<button onclick="run()" style="size:40%">Click me to start!</button>
<p id=output>(Output will display here).</p>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please explain exactly how to recreate the issue - I got `Distance between points (-10, -20) and (-12, -20) is 2`

Comment: Guess: try ```list.push([parseInt(x), parseInt(y)]);```

Comment: Hi. An input as 5, 8, 9, 4, 9, 2 works as intended, but 5, 8, 9, 4, -2, 20 throws the exception.

Comment: Actually, I just tried Gamma032's suggestion. This fixes the issue, thanks.